# Overflow Error with DMin Function in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm using DMin function in Ms-Access VBA, as below 
Dim MinVal as integer 
MinVal = DMin("ARRID", "Tbl_abc", "[RequestStatus] = 1 AND [WorkInProgress] = -1")

The above function was working fine untill now for almost a year, and all of a sudden it is giving me Overflow Error. i'm doing this Dmin on an Auto number, so there is no chance of Null/zeros.
Ideally the MinVal should be 40316 from the data which is not big number as well. I have tried compacting and reparing the database. still the problem persist.However, when i run the above DMin from an access query it is working fine. it is only in VBA it is not picking up.

Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `Dim MinVal As Integer` to `Dim MinVal As Long`. The maximum value of `Integer` (16-bits)is  32,767, whereas the max for `Long` (32-bits) is over 2 billion. Access stores Autonumbers as 32-bit Longs internally, so the queries have always worked. When you finished work on the last request that had ARRID  <=32767, your VBA had to put a 32-bit value into a 16-bit box. Overflow is your warning that the conversion would be incorrect. Make your box bigger!

Comment: I have changed it to Long and it workd thanks for your prompt response.